# How to get Xvfb to work on 32 bit color

Tags: linux, colors, bit

Can anybody tell me how to get Xvfb to work on 32bit color? Vnc4server works fine for example, but didn't fit my purpose.

```
> /etc/X11# Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x24
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
(EE) XKB: Couldn't open rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic, removing from list!
[config/hal] couldn't initialise context: (null) ((null))
FreeFontPath: FPE "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc" refcount is 2, should be 1; fixing.
```

Aka - it works, while:

```
> /etc/X11# Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x32
Fatal server error:
Couldn't add screen 0
```

Answer (score 50):

32 is no valid depth, see [this bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17453)

Try this instead: `Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x24+32`

Comment: Isn't that 32 just an offset, or is this a piece of undocumented syntax? 32bit is not a known color depth indeed ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth ).

Comment: @reim indeed that 32 is an offset